# How to find a modulus equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, computational-mathematics

Let $x$ and $q$ be an integer.Also, $a$ and $b$ are integers.

We know the two modulus equations.

i) $x \equiv y$ mod $p^a -1$

ii) $x \equiv z$ mod $p^b -1$

Then how to find $x$?
Can we find $x$ exactly? or Can we find the candidates of $x$? If then how many candidates of $x$?

Comment: Where is q? What is p?

Comment: Sorry, q is a power of p and p is a prime number

Comment: x to be found out in terms of which variables?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we do not have any $x$, but if we have one, then we have many. Let 
$h = (p^a -1)(p^b-1)+1$. Then we have
\begin{align}
h \equiv 1 \mod p^a-1
\\
h \equiv 1 \mod p^b-1
\end{align}
and if $x$ be a solution, then $hx$ is a solution too.

If $a \mid b$ or $b \mid a$ then $y$ and $z$ may be such that we 
do not have any choice for $x$. For example if $p = 2,a =2,b=4,y =2$ 
and $z = 0$ then there is no $x$ to fit in both equations.

In fact if we can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that 
\begin{equation}
(p^a - 1)x_1 \equiv z \mod p^b-1\\
(p^b - 1)x_2 \equiv y \mod p^a-1
\end{equation}
then $x = (p^a - 1)x_1 + (p^b - 1)x_2 + k(p^a -1)(p^b-1)$ gives a family of solutions. Based on this, we can say that if $(a,b)=1$ then (as 
$(p^a -1,p^b-1) = (a,b) $ ) always a solution exists.

Hope this be helpful.

---

Sorry! $(p^a -1,p^b-1) = p^{(a,b)}-1$, and my last result may not be true.

Comment: Commenting your last line. From $\gcd(p^a-1,p^b-1)=p^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ it follows that a solution exists if and only if $y$ and $z$ are congruent to each other modulo $p^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JyrkiLahtonen. Previously ,I was better in number theory.